# SQL Performance Query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    agen.id,agen.nome,agen.matricula,agen.tel_ben,agen.exames,agen.nome_contato,
    agen.tel_contato,agen.mail,agen.periodo_contato,agen.parentesco,agen.pedido_medico,agen.status 
CASE 
    WHEN txt_data is null 
    THEN datediff(curdate(), agen.dataHora) 
    ELSE datediff(curdate(), hist.txt_data) end as txt_ultimocontato
FROM agendamento agen
LEFT JOIN tb_historico hist on hist.id_agendamento = agen.id
WHERE status = 'N' 
ORDER BY txt_ultimocontato DESC 
LIMIT 0,100
```

Table agendamento

[image]

Table tb_historico

[image]

How can I improve this query , this very slow !

Comment: Please post the results of running `EXPLAIN <insert-your-select-query-here>;`

Comment: post all your involved tables structure and sample of data few records for every table. ideally provide an http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: index the tables agendamento and tb_historico.

As others have pointed out, please post the results of EXPLAIN <your query>

Answer (score 1):

You need indexes on any column involved in joins, in the where clause, and the order by clause. Without indexes the server must scan the whole tables to perform these things, and that is slow.

Learn how to get and how to interpret the "explain plan". This is the primary tool for tuning query performance, and you will have noticed comments requesting one.  The explain plans reveal if indexes are being used or not.

When providing table definitions also include the indexes on the table.